# change type of property in the interface with property value in typescript?

Tags: typescript, react-redux, interface, redux-toolkit

I have this interface for creating slice in redux-toolkit

```
interface AuthState {
  authenticated: boolean;
  role: number;
  currentUser: IUser | null;
  isAuthenticating: boolean;
}
```

is there any way to make `currentUser` always be `IUser` if `authenticated` is true?

So when access currentUser I don't have to check for `possibly null`. And a little explaination will help to cuz I'm new to `ts`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#discriminated-unions), discriminated on `authenticated` then [intersect](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) with the common properties:

```
type AuthStateUnion = {
  authenticated: true;
  currentUser: IUser;
} | {
  authenticated: false;
  currentUser: null;
}

type AuthState = AuthStateUnion & {
  role: number;
  isAuthenticating: boolean;
}

let state: AuthState = Math.random() > 0.5 ? {
  authenticated: true,
  currentUser : { name: ""},
  role: 1,
  isAuthenticating: false
} :{
  authenticated: false,
  currentUser : null,
  role: 1,
  isAuthenticating: false
} 

if (state.authenticated) {
  state.currentUser.name
} else {
  state.currentUser // null
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQFUBnNAbziUwFtgAuOYmKZAczgF8AoGATzDwBBAK4wAFgGUYmVISQIISOAF44ZLnDiZRY4CgTYZwACYNmw4AG4NcbMKhQ9MEmgZFSUaxzgAfNTe1xJwMjUzgsABtSa007BycXKAYkYQiIry4efiEdKSMVOBFxPNl5RTgAMn9NKAgI+kphagAjNBjEYiLdfUMYNgZmiDrgTCQMrnr4JiMGLpK8VQBZGTEAOihR4whqAAoASjgAPjgABlWAVjgAfmqtHWDekzMoCwAaGzjHFES4BgoqWgMABEQI47xqwwYAEZwR0ug8ZP1wpgosAuN46OpNIFun1HmFIqRYZ8Eh5fo00rDavVobCEJ17j1EUhWAxCWjvJkEOg4DtpqhVjiEahjAcsYxpAKSd8PKsARy4MBUbd+cBVtLnGSAPRaikRdFAA)

Comment: But then I get `Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'false'` or `Type 'IUser' is not assignable to type 'null'`, it doesn't assign to the value a gave them

Comment: @Gr4y depends what you are assigning. I added examples of valid value that can be assigned.

Comment: Sorry if I made this unclear but the behavior I want is to check if `authenticated == true` then `currentUser` will not be null. in the example I can still make `authenticated == true` and `currentUser == null`

Comment: @Gr4y Not sure I understand what you are saying. In the example, inside the `if`, `currentUser` is typed as `IUser` on the true branch and as `null` on the else branch